# In Swift iOS, is there a way to detect light intesity levels on individual SCNNodes?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, scenekit

I am looking for a way to evaluate if a narrow spot light (which the user can move around the scene) is directly positioned onto SCNNodes. I would like the node to "react" and execute an action once the spot "hits" it.  I have looked into using the LightType probe, but it doesn't appear to have accessible values.